# Look like Script Text is Limited to 2869 characters in Invoke-VMScript in PowerCLI. How to run large Script?

Tags: powershell, invoke, powercli

```
$scriptText = {Very Large script with more than 2869 Characters}
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptType Powershell -VM $vmname -GuestUser $guser -GuestPassword $gpassword -ScriptText $ScriptText
```

When I try to run Script having characters more than 2869, Script doesn't execute.
It executes fine when its less than 2870 characters.

Is there a way to execute large script?

Comment: I dont think there is any way to do that apart from breaking into multiple scripts.

Comment: Agree with Ranadip. If the script can be broken up, break it up. If it can't, send the text to a file locally, then execute the script on the client side.